# ASP.NET MVC manage objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

NET MVC, now i have a situation where in my controller i'm creating a partial view when a button is clicked and the model of the view holds a class which listens to events.

```
StreamModel streamModel = m_StreamModel = new StreamModel(cameraId, rgsLiveVideoWebCall);

string view = RenderRazorViewToString("ImageView", streamModel);

public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                     viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                         ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

the StreamModel class looks like this:

```
public class StreamModel
{
    public StreamHolder StreamHolder { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public StreamModel(string cameraId, string url)
    {
        StreamHolder = new StreamHolder(cameraId, url);
    }
}
```

and the StreamHolder holder class like this:

```
public class StreamHolder
{
    private object GetNewImageLock = new object();

    public string CameraId { get; set; }

    private MJPEGStream m_MJPEGStream;

    public byte[] CurrentImageBytes { get; set; }

    public string ImageBase64 { get; set; }


    public StreamHolder(string cameraId, string url)
    {
        CameraId = cameraId;
        CurrentImageBytes = null;
        ImageBase64 = null;
        lock (this)
        {
            m_MJPEGStream = new MJPEGStream(url);
            m_MJPEGStream.RequestTimeout = 100000;
            m_MJPEGStream.ForceBasicAuthentication = true;
            m_MJPEGStream.Login = "admin";
            m_MJPEGStream.Password = "admin";
            m_MJPEGStream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;
            m_MJPEGStream.PlayingFinished += stream_PlayingFinished;
            m_MJPEGStream.VideoSourceError += stream_VideoSourceError;
            m_MJPEGStream.Start();
        }
    }

    public void StopStreaming()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (m_MJPEGStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    m_MJPEGStream.Stop();
                    m_MJPEGStream.WaitForStop();
                    m_MJPEGStream.NewFrame -= stream_NewFrame;
                    m_MJPEGStream.PlayingFinished -= stream_PlayingFinished;
                    m_MJPEGStream.VideoSourceError -= stream_VideoSourceError;
                    m_MJPEGStream = null;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }

    private void stream_VideoSourceError(object sender, VideoSourceErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        StopStreaming();
    }

    private void stream_PlayingFinished(object sender, ReasonToFinishPlaying reason)
    {
        StopStreaming();
    }

    private void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        lock (GetNewImageLock)
        {
            if (HomeController.m_LastImageRequest != null && (DateTime.Now - HomeController.m_LastImageRequest).TotalSeconds > 10)
            {
                StopStreaming();
                return;
            }

            if (eventArgs.Frame != null)
            {
                CurrentImageBytes = BitmapToBytes(eventArgs.Frame);
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(CurrentImageBytes);
                ImageBase64 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
            }
        }
    }

    // This method is for converting bitmap into a byte array
    private static byte[] BitmapToBytes(Bitmap img)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            stream.Close();
            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

i have 2 main problems:
1) i may have more than 1 instance of this Model, and i need to access and manage them after they were created.
2) i need to dispose them correctly when the tab/window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a

```
private static List<StreamModel> streamModels = new List<StreamModel>();
```

in one of your classes. You can define a method, like this one:

```
public static StreamModel generateStreamModel(string cameraid, string url) {
    StreamModel streamModel = new StreamModel(cameraid, url);
    streamModels.Add(streamModel);
    return streamModel;
}
```

To dispose an instance you remove it from `streamModels`. If it is unreferenced, it should be collected by the Garbage Collector.

Comment: Entry point is controller action method which links all the objects so wouldn't it all get collected by GC when request is served and controller instance get's disposed?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya already tried the solution with a static list, i know it works the problem is that the StreamHolder object is listening to events, which are being sent from a remote server, so even after the dispose of the controller the object is still listening to the events and the remote server doesn't know when to stop its work/sending events

Comment: @user1531186 Static list is not associated with instance so it wont get disposed with that disposal of instance but instance member should get disposed when instance itself gets disposed.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya i know, the idea is the each object is getting images from an open stream, now i need to close the stream(StopStreaming method) in case the user will close the tab/window, but how will i know that happened(part 2 of the question)?